# Docker: WORKDIR create a layer?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#minimize-the-number-of-layers

After read the above doc, I tested to prove the following statement:

> Only the instructions RUN, COPY, ADD create layers. Other instructions create temporary intermediate images, and do not increase the size of the build.

My envs are:

```sh
❯ sw_vers
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 11.6.1
BuildVersion:   20G224

❯ docker version
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.22
 Version:           20.10.13
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.15
 Git commit:        a224086
 Built:             Thu Mar 10 14:08:44 2022
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Desktop 4.6.1 (76265)
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.13
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.16.15
  Git commit:       906f57f
  Built:            Thu Mar 10 14:06:05 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.5.10
  GitCommit:        2a1d4dbdb2a1030dc5b01e96fb110a9d9f150ecc
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.3
  GitCommit:        v1.0.3-0-gf46b6ba
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0

❯ dive --version
dive 0.10.0
# installed from brew
```

Following Dockerfile, using to test, cotains all instruction but it doesn't make sense quietly(Some of them are not used, so it does not cover all possibilities maybe):

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM alpine:3.15.4
LABEL name=layer
EXPOSE 3456
ENV APP=layer
ADD add.tar.gz /
COPY copy /copy
ENTRYPOINT ["date"]
RUN rm /bin/arch
CMD ["--help"]
VOLUME /log
USER root
ARG workdir
WORKDIR $workdir
ONBUILD RUN echo 'b'
STOPSIGNAL SIGTERM
HEALTHCHECK CMD which date
SHELL ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
```

Build and inspect the image, the name as `layer`, it has 5 layers:

```sh
# Preparation: create build contexts for ADD and COPY
> mkdir add
> dd if=/dev/urandom of=add/1 bs=1M count=1
> dd if=/dev/urandom of=add/2 bs=1M count=1
> dd if=/dev/urandom of=copy bs=1M count=1
> tar -cf add.tar add
> gzip add.tar

# Build
❯ docker build --build-arg workdir=/etc -t layer .
(...eliding)

# Inspect
❯ docker inspect layer | jq '.[0].RootFS.Layers | length'
5
```

Inspect with `dive`, there are unexpected instructions which make layers, `FROM` and `WORKDIR` :

```sh
# the left pane of `dive layer'
┃  ●  Layers ┣ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ │
Cmp   Size  Command                                                   
    5.6 MB  FROM 8792aa27a60beb9                                       
    2.1 MB  ADD add.tar.gz / # buildkit                                
    1.0 MB  COPY copy /copy # buildkit                                 
       0 B  RUN /bin/sh -c rm /bin/arch # buildkit                     
       0 B  WORKDIR /etc
```

Except RUN, ADD and COPY, there is other instructions that create a image layer?

- For FROM, it seem reasonable somehow
- **But for WORKDIR, Why? Can I get the references about it?**

+ Like `dive`, how could I map between the image layer digest and the command each ?

```sh
❯ docker inspect layer | jq '.[0].RootFS.Layers[]'
"sha256:4fc242d58285699eca05db3cc7c7122a2b8e014d9481f323bd9277baacfa0628"
"sha256:38df8fd6b1d0100d029b0cfa3611ee48cf2d0e2d71856dab9b3c818ae180e100"
"sha256:deab9dc570f38644bbad2bb4a9a91ecec8afdbd4dbd7ed3bae4c3c63e84b1924"
"sha256:34b91600d244859b8ce5aaf493bed6c778c933d51d7f72df7f9ab426f55d50db"
"sha256:5f70bf18a086007016e948b04aed3b82103a36bea41755b6cddfaf10ace3c6ef"
```

---

#### Update

After the several times of recreating image, it has 4 layers except for WORKDIR. It seems undeterminitic...:

```sh
❯ docker inspect layer | jq -r '.[0].RootFS.Layers[]' | wc -l
4

# the leftpane in dive
┃  ●  Layers ┣ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━ ━
Cmp   Size  Command                                                    
    5.6 MB  FROM 8792aa27a60beb9                                       
    2.1 MB  ADD add.tar.gz / # buildkit                                
    1.0 MB  COPY copy /copy # buildkit                                 
       0 B  RUN /bin/sh -c rm /bin/arch # buildkit
```

Comment: Try the WORKDIR instruction hardcoded without depending on an ARG. Maybe that causes another layer

Comment: No, I've changed the WORKDIR parameter as '/etc' then rebuild, both use cache and with `--no-cache`, the result image has same 5 layers, also for the digests.

Comment: Weird.. Now it has 4 layers, without WORKDIR's one, after recreating images several times .

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a documentation "bug" in the best practices document. A better way to have phrased this is that only those commands you mention will create layers **that increase the total build size**.

Note that the layers you're seeing are 0 bytes, as opposed to the FROM, ADD, COPY which each have an associated size (the amount they contribute to the total filesystem growth).

```
Cmp   Size  Command                                                   
    5.6 MB  FROM 8792aa27a60beb9                                       
    2.1 MB  ADD add.tar.gz / # buildkit                                
    1.0 MB  COPY copy /copy # buildkit                                 
       0 B  RUN /bin/sh -c rm /bin/arch # buildkit                     
       0 B  WORKDIR /etc
```

A layer exists for WORKDIR - but it's metadata. A layer exists for the `rm` command, but all it adds is a "file deleted" marker - not actual file contents. So they contribute nothing to the eventual filesystem size in the image.

As for FROM, that doesn't, in and of itself, create a layer - it imports a starting image. The reference could be clearer about that, I guess, but either way it would confuse someone. They must assume it's obvious that FROM contributes to the size (unless you are using `FROM scratch`).

I wasn't able to find a definitive reference about this. A reading of the source code might be the only such reference available.